# Suppose n is a positive integer and n > 1. Prove (algebraically) that {n\choose 2} + {n-1\choose 2} is a perfect square

Tags: combinatorics

Do I prove this by choosing a number for n and simplifying it out or do I need to simplify it with the n and prove its equal to the definition of a perfect square?

I've done a couple of numbers as n and they've come out as perfect squares but I don't know what I need to write to prove algebraically that it's true

Comment: I'm not sure why my tex command for n choose k notation isn't working. Sorry

Comment: The statement as I read it is to prove that it is true *for all* $n$.  Just choosing one value of $n$ arbitrarily and showing that it results in a perfect square only proves it true for that one case out of the infinitely many cases that you are asked to prove.  No, you may *not* just choose an arbitrary value.

Comment: So to solve I need to simplify out both cases and prove that when they're added together they equal the mathematical definition of a perfect square number?

Comment: Yes.  It shouldn't be that bad., you are just adding two quadratics together.

Comment: Hint :
\begin{eqnarray*}
\binom{n}{2}=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 1):

$$\binom {n}{2} + \binom {n-1}{2} = \frac {n(n-1)}{2} + \frac {(n-1)(n-2)}{2}=  $$

$$\frac {(n-1)(n+n-2)}{2} = (n-1)^2$$